# JavaScript canvas.toDataURL method returns blank image

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I know this question has already been asked several times, however, I haven't 
found a solution yet.

I want to take an image, rotate it and put it in a HTML canvas, to do this I'm using another canvas in which I rotate the image, this part works well, however, when I try to take the image from the second canvas using .toDataUrl, it returns a blank image. The code is the following

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
      <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <canvas id=canvas height="400" width="400" style="border: 10px solid orange"></canvas>
  <canvas id=canvasTransform height="183" width="183" style="border: 10px solid orange"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      //this is the canvas in which I want to put the rotated image
      var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
      var context=canvas.getContext("2d");

      //and I use this one to rotate it
      var canvasTransform=document.getElementById('canvasTransform');
      var contextTransform=canvasTransform.getContext("2d");

      var image=new Image(46,183);
      image.onload=function(){
        contextTransform.drawImage(image,0,0);
      }
      image.src="Fireball.png";
      console.log(image.src);
      //Now I rotate the context
      contextTransform.rotate(-0.25*Math.PI);
      //After doing this, I can see the rotated image in the second canvas, however, the following line returns a blank image
      var rotatedImageURL=canvasTransform.toDataURL();
      console.log(rotatedImageURL);
      //Finally, this part isn't wornking since I just draw a blank image
      var rotatedImage=new Image();
      rotatedImage.onload=function(){
        context.drawImage(rotatedImage,0,0);
      }
      rotatedImage.src=rotatedImageURL;

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

I have been stuck here for a while, so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely need to wait until after drawing the image before calling toDataURL. The fireball is only drawn after the image is loaded but the rotate (and everything after that) is called right after registering the onload event handler (but before it has actually loaded).

Comment: Thanks! I finally understand what was happening, moving everything except for the line in which I set the path to the image inside the handler solved the problem

Comment: You're very welcome :) Remember to mark the question as resolved!